# Xcode SIGABRT when accessing photo gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera, sigabrt

I've been trying to get my application to select a photo from the photo gallery and then display it, it worked in a different project fine, but in this one the application runs fine but when I press the UIButton that is supposed to bring up the gallery, I get the error SIGABRT in main.m on int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

As I said, this has worked fine in the past so I don't know why it isn't now, here's the parts of the code related to the error, I'm only posting that as I've got a lot of code and it's easier this way.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    //Blah blah blah
}

//Blah blah blah
-(IBAction) selectExistingpicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;

//Blah blah blah

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize theImageView;

-(IBAction) selectExistingPicture
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    theImageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have linked selectExistingPicture to a UIButton but I don't know what's causing that button to cause me errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post any console output about a stack trace?

Comment: 2011-07-26 22:08:44.016 Jail Time[6923:207] -[ViewController selectExistingpicture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b46c20
2011-07-26 22:08:44.020 project[6923:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController selectExistingpicture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b46c20'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: is that a iPad or iPhone App???

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i use my camera roll

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,
                                        nil];

    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];


}

else {
    NSLog(@"Error");

}
```

the thing that i see wrong with yours is

```
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```

which should be

```
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Also you appear to be missing

```
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,
                                    nil];
```

Take a look at how i have mine set up

Comment: I've tried replacing just the picker.sourcetype and the whole thing with yours but I still get the same problem (and I'm not getting the NSLog to say error in my console).

Comment: Okay, i would give this a try, put a NSLog into the if statement, see if its even trying to run the photo album, put the NSLog right at the beginning

Comment: Okay, I fixed the problem with selectExistingpicture and selectExistingPicture to get it to get SIGABRT on a line in the code that accesses the photo gallery, so I reverted to my method from yours and it now works fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad i could help, just a tip..More people will answer your questions if you accept the answer. Just press the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the photo gallery. It probably never executes `selectExistingPicture` in the first place.

Possible problems:

1. The view controller isn't an instance of `ViewController` because you didn't specify the correct class in IB.
2. You write `selectExistingpicture` instead of `selectExistingPicture` (lower vs. upper case P) in a few places.

Answer (score 0):

`selectExistingpicture` != `selectExistingPicture`...

that is you declare `selectExistingpicture` then define `selectExistingPicture` which is why your autocomplete would select `selectExistingpicture` for you, as it exists in your .h file, this mis-match will cause a compiler warning... change all instances to proper camelCased `selectExistingPicture` and you will be fine... well at least that error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, you have a typo (incorrect case on selectExistingPicture), noted for you right there in the error message:

> reason: '-[ViewController selectExistingpicture]: unrecognized
>   selector